# Stored procedure with HTML output or simple HTML website

Tags: php, html, sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm currently working with stored procedures and I'm trying to setup simple website/output with HTML.

My boss wants to have an simple "type-in box" where he will be able to type inn email address so he can get employee number and name from our database. I have never worked with stored procedures, so I'm just learning right now.

Can someone provide me an simple code that we could use here and test out?

SQL query is something like this:

```
select empnum, name 
from users 
where email = 'david@domain.com'
```

- `empnum` is the employee numer
- `name` is name and surname

What we want to accomplish is to have opportunity to type email address f.ex david@domain.com and get employee number and name as an Output in browser.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ext_test1 
    @email VARCHAR(15)
```

This is command that I have started with. Same command that we used before in another cases.

Have any of you any idea how we could do that? Im not very familiar with stored procedures in SQL Servre 2012 so I need to ask you guys.

So simply: It could be great to have simple html box where we could just type in email address and get employee number and name.

Comment: Sample code can be found **in the manual**

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.ext_test1
(
    @email VARCHAR(15)
)
AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT empnum, name
    FROM users
    WHERE email LIKE '%' + @email + '%'

END
GO
```

Comment: Thanks but we want to have something like search box in HTML or something. It could work but in this case, we would be forced to type in email address in links. Could you provide HTML code with sotre procedure?

Comment: We would like to have simple HTML search box where we or user could type in email address to one person, and get simple table with employee number and name

Comment: Check about `LIKE` operator

Answer (score 0):

```
 Try this
 DELIMITER //
   create procedure getEmployDetail(IN email varchar(32))
    BEGIN
     select Employee_Number,Employee_Name from table_name where 
     email=@email;
    END
 DELIMITER ;

//Here there are two email variable one is column name from your table 
// Call this procedure as call getEmployDetail(david@domain.com);
// then you will get Employee number and Employee Name
```

Comment: Can you provide simple html code with store procedure so we could have an text box in web browser where we could type in email address and get simple html table with employee number and name? Thank you!

Comment: we can not call stored procedure from html..we need server side programm(php,jsp,python) to call proc

Comment: What about an output in table? Like in powershell. So you execute store procedure and get output in html or simple table?